# How do I find the plain version of a font in Core Text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-text

I'm using `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` to create a `CTFontRef` with an italic version (`kCTFontItalicTrait`). Is there a way of taking the same italic font and using `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` to set it back to the plain version again?

Thanks!

Comment: For your reference, to format inline code properly, surround it in backticks (`), not single-quotes (') (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code). I've fixed it here.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the trait you want to remove in the mask, and 0 for the value, like this:

```
CTFontRef normalFont
  = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(italicFont,           // italic font
                                       0,                    // keep size
                                       NULL,                 // keep matrix 
                                       0,                    // value = 0
                                       kCTFontItalicTrait);  // mask = italic
```